# temporarily stop Firefox to prevent battery drain

Tags: firefox, power-management, battery, killall

Firefox drains my batteries (bad habit of the lazybone), so I would like to STOP it for a while and then resume it again. I tried killall but without much success:

```
$ ps h kpcpu -eo pcpu,comm | tail -n2
 3.2 wget
35.7 firefox
$ killall -i -s STOP  firefox
Signal firefox(9661) senden? (y/N) y
$ ps h kpcpu -eo pcpu,comm | tail -n2
 3.3 wget
35.7 firefox
$ killall -s CONT  firefox
$ ps h kpcpu -eo pcpu,comm | tail -n2
 3.4 wget
35.5 firefox
```

Well, the stopped firefox does not react to mouse anymore, but as you see it keeps on draining MY batteries. Do I deserve such a treatment??? 
Is there any smart genius to persuade firefox to behave bravely? :-)

Comment: When you want to suspend Firefox for awhile to save battery life and then resume it later, why don't you simply close the window and all tabs and then reopen it from launcher having it restore all previously opened tabs? Sounds simpler and I'm sure if Chrome can reopen all tabs from previous session Fire Fox can do it to.

Comment: Well, if you do edit something, say Wikipedia, it cannot be restored...